# How to see Jenkins Declarative Pipeline's test results in the Dashboard View?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Our team is using cloud Jenkins server and creating the test jobs using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline. During run-time it creates the Jenkins node pull Selenoid and browser images and executes the java/maven test scripts.

We have added the dashboard view plugin for consolidated view in Jenkins with test statistics grid, test statistics chart and test trend chart.

**The test execution results are not getting picked up by these charts on dashboard view.**

Do we have any way/mechanism the test results executing in declarative pipeline can be read by Jenkins and picked up the dashboard view?

Maven jobs created in Jenkins directly passes the test execution information like status (pass, failed, skipped) in the dashboard view for statistics and charts.

Part of the Maven pipeline added here below

```
container('maven') {
            stage('test') {
                sh 'mvn test -s settings.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=remote -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true'
            }
        }

    }

    stage('logs') {
        containerLog('maven')
        containerLog('chrome')
        containerLog('jnlp')
        containerLog('selenoid-ui')
        containerLog('selenoid-hub')
    }
```